# how do I resize a div based on the size of another div inside?

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical nav "slider" that now needs to be dynamically resized based in the number of links available to the user.  I've searched all over, but all the solutions I've found haven't quite worked.  It may simply be the way I have my css working. Any time I try to change the height attribute, the whole thing goes haywire.  I'm trying to do this entirely in css.  I know it seems like it should be simple, I just can't figure it out myself.

It's basically:

```
<div class="slideMenu">
    <ul class="nav">menu items...</ul>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
.slideMenu {
  background: #449bb5;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: -180px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 100;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.slideMenu:not(:hover) {
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

.slideMenu:hover {
  transform: translate3d(160px, 0, 0);
}

.slideMenu .nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vwvwkfgb/)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: which 'height' are you trying to change and what is the actual problem? (Your JSFiddle looks fine to me, but I'm not sure what you see as being wrong with it)

Comment: Not at all sure I know what you mean, but maybe removing most of your styles on `.slideMenu .nav` would do it?  I may be completely off base, but is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/g70xwo92/

Comment: ok I'm sorry I wasn't very clear.  Sometimes the menu items (nav) might be 12, sometimes 3, sometimes whatever.  I need "slideMenu" which is the container to shrink or grow depending on the number of menu items showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify a height.  Doing so in this instance with 100% says that the height is 100% of it's parent container... The body.  Not what you want.  Leave it out.  You have other issues here that you can improve, which I marked in the comments of the code below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif" !important;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.slideMenu {
  background: #449bb5;
  width: 140px;
  /* height: 100%; remove this */
  padding-right: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  left: -180px;
  top: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 100;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}

.slideMenu:not(:hover) {
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

.slideMenu:hover/*, .slideMenu:focus*/ {
  transform: translate3d(160px, 0, 0);
}


.slideMenu .nav {
  /*position: absolute; changed to relative */
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  /* height: auto; remove. unnecessary */
  /*
  -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  remove this. it's trying to center your menu */
  font-weight: 400;
}

.slideMenu .nav li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slideMenu .nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slideMenu .nav li a:hover {
  color: #aaa;
}

.slideMenuTab {
 background: #449bb5;
 position: relative;
 width: 40px;
 z-index: 3;
 -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 left: 165px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: right;
 padding-right: 8px;
 padding-top: 6px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideMenu">
   <div class="slideMenuTab"><img src="images/hamburger.png"/></div>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="PickTicket">Create Pick</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="ReturnTicket">Create Return</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="AdjustmentTicket">Create Adjustment</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="CreateMTRTicket">Create MTR</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="ReceiveMTRTicket">Receive MTR</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a href="https://ecom.schwarz.com" target="_blank" data-type="ticketdialogbutton">Order Signage</a>       </li>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="PickTicket">Create Pick</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="ReturnTicket">Create Return</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="AdjustmentTicket">Create Adjustment</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="CreateMTRTicket">Create MTR</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="ReceiveMTRTicket">Receive MTR</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a href="https://ecom.schwarz.com" target="_blank" data-type="ticketdialogbutton">Order Signage</a>       </li>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="PickTicket">Create Pick</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="ReturnTicket">Create Return</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="AdjustmentTicket">Create Adjustment</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="CreateMTRTicket">Create MTR</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a data-type="ticketdialogbutton" data-class="ReceiveMTRTicket">Receive MTR</a></li>
      <hr>
      <li><a href="https://ecom.schwarz.com" target="_blank" data-type="ticketdialogbutton">Order Signage</a></li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Wade!  That did it!  Did a little minor tweaking, but it works beautifully!